# Loading dates from a CSV file to MySQL via Talend, 2020-03-30 appears as 2020-03-29 and from then on the dates are +1 day

Tags: mysql, csv, talend

I've been using Talend to load data to MySQL from CSV for a while but recently come across a problem whereby the dates mess up as it hits 2020-03-30.

I've loaded just a file of dates to find where the problem lies and below (attached images) is what i have loaded vs what is shown in SQL.

To note, this happens for every year and is not only happening for dates in 2020.
Along with this the 29th March is duplicated and the 25th October is removed - therefore all of the dates between 29th March and 25th October are incorrect by 1 day and any dates outside of these are fine.

All of this is done via the simple mapping:
Input: tFileInputDelimited
Processing: tMap
Output: SQLtable

The date format used is "yyyy-MM-dd" on both sides when mapping.

[image: CSV file dates - loaded]
[image: SQL dates - result]

Comment: Are you loading data in your system or any other server?

Comment: I'm loading data into a server.

Comment: you are loading from your system to server right?

Comment: That looks like data duplication to me. Could you post a sample query?

Comment: Yes loading straight from my system (desktop) into the server.

Sorry would you like a sample query from Talend or SQL?

I have just found that the issue corrects itself when it hits November, so it is duplicating 29th March and for some reason skipping 25th October - i will add this to the main query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens with Talend when the transfer is being made from one environment to another. For example, from file to DB or from 1 Db server to another one. I have a way around for it. I declare the column as string in Talend's schema & set the **datetime** datatype in the Database. This resolves the issue. Below the screenshot from Talend's job:
[image]